# PROC SQL with merge with two where statement and in a single dataset

Tags: sas

```
data a;
set b1(where=(PARAMCD='ABC') rename=(aval=abc) in=a) b1(where=(PARAMCD='CDE') rename=(aval=cde));
by usubjid  AVISITN;
if a;
PARAMCD="ASD";

AVAL=mean(abc,cde);
run;
```

I have a single dataset in SAS where several paramcd i need to filter two paramcd and avg of those value. I need to create a proc sql syntax to have merge issue to be solved.

Comment: The question seems a bit off.. It looks like merge, but the datasets are both **B1**.

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you mean by SQL merge issue to be solved.  It would be helpful to include an example of the SQL code you would try to solve this with and see if you can explain where you think that is problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just want to join a table with itself.  Try something like this.

```
proc sql ;
create table a as
  select a.usubjid
       , a.avisitn
       , a.aval as abc
       , b.aval as cde
       , mean(a.aval,b.aval) as aval
  from b1 a
  left join b1 b
  on a.usubjid = b.usubjid
  and a.avisitn = b.avisitn
  and a.paramcd='ABC'
  and b.paramcd='CDE'
;
quit;
```

Or you could use sub-queries to replicate the where= dataset option.

```
create table a as
  select a.usubjid
       , a.avisitn
       , a.aval as abc
       , b.aval as cde
       , mean(a.aval,b.aval) as aval
  from (select * from b1 where paramcd='ABC') a
  left join (select * from b1 where paramcd='CDE') b
  on a.usubjid = b.usubjid
  and a.avisitn = b.avisitn
;
```

Comment: Okay. This works, but could anyone clarify why would one want to left join one and the same table? I fail to see the reason. Maybe I'm just missing something obvious. What could it be?

Comment: @pinegulf The reason is the the source table is name/value pair table. So need to match two rows to find the average of the two values.